# How does a new blank frame come out after inserting a longtable

Tags: beamer, longtable

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=1]{result}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{longtable}{rlr}
    \toprule
    classifier & preprocess &  error rate(\%) \\
    \midrule
    LMS   & compressed, PCA & 21.52 \\
    LMS   & compressed, FE & 22.6 \\
    LMS   & compressed, deskewed, FE & 14.43 \\
    LMS   & compressed, deskewed,  & 12.37 \\
    3-NN  & compressed & 5.46 \\
    3-NN  & compressed, deskewed & 4.1 \\
    3-NN  & compressed, PCA & 4.7 \\
    3-NN  & compressed, deskewed, PCA & 9.76 \\
    \newpage
    3-NN  & compressed, FE & 9.76 \\
    3-NN  & compressed, deskewed, FE & 7.03 \\
    Adaboost.MH & compressed, PCA & 15.57 \\
    Adaboost.MH & compressed, deskewed, PCA & 10.83 \\
    Adaboost.MH & compressed, FE & 8.76 \\
    Adaboost.MH & compressed, deskewed, FE & 7.24 \\
    ANN(50-49-1) & compressed, PCA & 24.96 \\
    ANN(50-6-1) & compressed, PCA & 24.59 \\
    ANN(50-9-1) & compressed, PCA & 29.38 \\
    \newpage
    ANN(166-165-1) & compressed, deskewed, FE & 31.49 \\
    ANN(166-7-1) & compressed, deskewed, FE & 22.73 \\
    ANN(166-15-1) & compressed, deskewed, FE & 28.02 \\
    ANN(50-49-1) & compressed, deskewed, PCA & 21.63 \\
    ANN(50-6-1) & compressed, deskewed, PCA & 11.37 \\
    ANN(50-9-1) & compressed, deskewed, PCA & 23.17 \\
    \bottomrule
  \caption{error rate}

  \label{tab:errRate}%
\end{longtable}%  
\end{table}

\end{frame}
```

I don't know why a new blank frame come out after this frame? How to eliminate it? I am using `ctex`.

Comment: Why a longtable in a presentation I will never understand...

Comment: Since I have a long table to present

Comment: Not a full solution, but a hint: the `caption` has to be outside of the `longtable`environment. If you do that, your previously empty frame is not empty anymore, but contains the caption. So if you do not really need the caption you could remove the whole `table` environment and the empty slide disappears.

Comment: Yes. I put the caption outside the longtable environment previously, however, the last frame only contained the caption. But when put inside, it came out a new blank frame. If I need the caption, what else could I do? Is there another way to display longtable without removing the caption? I have tried xtab however failed to compile the code.

Comment: Can you please provide a compilable MWE? Including `documentclass` etc.?